# XML to CSV conversion using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

i am trying to convert XML to csv using xslt, i am not familiar with xslt so just reading some tutorial and other online resources.
Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<impex>
    <test>
        <Employee />
        <UID>auma</UID>
        <Name>HR Manager</Name>
        <Groups />
        <Password>228781</Password>
    </test>
    <test>
        <Employee />
        <UID>auma1</UID>
        <Name>HR Manager</Name>
        <Groups />
        <Password>2287811</Password>
    </test>
</impex>
```

i am using the following XSL for the conversion of xml to csv

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:f="Functions"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text" />
 <xsl:param name="headerVal" select="'INSERT_UPDATE Employee;UID[unique=true];name;groups(uid);password'"/>


<xsl:template match="/impex">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="test[1]/*" mode="header"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="test" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*" mode="header" >

    <xsl:value-of select="$headerVal" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" >
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>;</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i am trying to define my csv header using  but this is not working for me

csv output

```
INSERT_UPDATEEmployeeUID[unique=true]namegroups(uid)password
INSERT_UPDATEEmployeeUID[unique=true]namegroups(uid)password
INSERT_UPDATEEmployeeUID[unique=true]namegroups(uid)password
INSERT_UPDATEEmployeeUID[unique=true]namegroups(uid)password
INSERT_UPDATEEmployeeUID[unique=true]namegroups(uid)password
;auma;HR Manager;;228781
;auma1;HR Manager;;2287811
```

as below line

```
<xsl:param name="headerVal" select="'INSERT_UPDATE Employee;UID[unique=true];name;groups(uid);password'"/>
```

I was assuming that it was due to `;` in the `select` value but i even removed it and even removed the space but nothing helped 
i have googled about this but unable to find a way as how to define this header inside my xsl file so that i can use this header for my csv

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="test[1]/*" mode="header"/>
```

Here I was selecting all elements inside `test[1]` and in my XML I have five elements inside the `test` element, so I just changed this line to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="test[1]" mode="header"/>
```

and it working fine.

Comment: Thank you SOOO much for posting this.  It was the answer to my problem--doing something very similar.

Essentially, I also need to convert XML to CSV.  My output is more traditionally formatted than yours (no INSERT statements at the top).

Regardless, the mode="header" trick was what I was missing.

Again, thank you /very/ much.