# How can I convert ods to xlsx in java

Tags: java, csv, ms-office, opendocument, jodconverter

I wrote code that creates one ods file from csv but this file is not opening in Office 2007. How can I convert it into xlsx format in Java?

Comment: 1) *"creates one ods file"*  Does it open correctly in Open Office Calc?  It might not be a valid ODS file.  2) Why not import the CSV directly into Office?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML to CSV conversion using XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091009/xml-to-csv-conversion-using-xslt)